# Sql to find the most frequent start time of an employee

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[image]

I have a table with weekly data of the start time of employees,
How to write the most efficient SQL to find the most common start date for each day in the week?

I expect to get some thing like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [APPROX_TOP_COUNT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/approximate_aggregate_functions#approx_top_count):

```
with mytable as (
    select 'Mary' as employeer, '14:00' as Shift_S1, '9:00' as Shift_S2 union all
    select 'Mary', '12:00', '7:00' union all
    select 'Mary', '14:00', '7:00'
)
select employeer, APPROX_TOP_COUNT(Shift_S1, 1)[OFFSET(0)].value as Shift_S1, APPROX_TOP_COUNT(Shift_S2, 1)[OFFSET(0)].value as Shift_S2
from mytable
group by employeer
```

[image]

Update for ignoring NULLs:

```
with mytable as (
    select 'Mary' as employeer, '14:00' as Shift_S1, '9:00' as Shift_S2 union all
    select 'Mary', '12:00', '7:00' union all
    select 'Mary', '14:00', '7:00' union all
    select 'Mary', NULL, NULL union all
    select 'Mary', NULL, NULL union all
    select 'Mary', NULL, '8:00'
)
select
    employeer,
    IFNULL(APPROX_TOP_COUNT(Shift_S1, 2)[OFFSET(0)].value, APPROX_TOP_COUNT(Shift_S1, 2)[OFFSET(1)].value) as Shift_S1,
    IFNULL(APPROX_TOP_COUNT(Shift_S2, 2)[OFFSET(0)].value, APPROX_TOP_COUNT(Shift_S2, 2)[OFFSET(1)].value) as Shift_S2
from mytable
group by employeer
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a problem with this solution and it is not going to return expected result and rather most of the shifts will have NULL as a most frequent value. Why? Because as you can see data is sparse - so many values are NULLs and APPROX_TOP_COUNT does not ignore NULLs so they also will be considered as a candidates for most frequent time

Comment: Good point! Thank you @MikhailBerlyant

Comment: Change `OFFSET` to `SAFE_OFFSET` in case there is only one value and I reckon this is a very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select employee, shift, array_agg(start_time order by freq desc limit 1)[offset(0)] start_time
  from (
    select employee, shift, start_time, count(1) freq
    from mytable
    unpivot (start_time for shift in (Shift_S1, Shift_S2, Shift_S3, Shift_S4, Shift_S5, Shift_S6, Shift_S7))
    group by employee, shift, start_time
  )
  group by employee, shift
)
pivot (min(start_time) for shift in ('Shift_S1', 'Shift_S2', 'Shift_S3', 'Shift_S4', 'Shift_S5', 'Shift_S6', 'Shift_S7'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]